# libGDX: deforming an existing 3d model

Tags: java, animation, 3d, libgdx

Imagine I have, let's say, a 3d model of a worm created in Blender. This worm model consists of three segments: a head segment, a middle segment and a tail segment, each of which is controlled by a single bone. Now what I want is to be able to scale those segments inside my application (and thereby change the length of the worm) by using something like this:

```
middleBone.scaleX(1.5);
```

Of course, I could create an animation in Blender that does what I want, but than I would need a single animation for each scale-value and also, I would need an `AnimationController`, although I don't really want to animate something, but just change the scale of a single part of my worm permanently. So, is there any way to access a single bone inside my libGDX game? Or is there any better way to solve this problem?